# Hibernate Criteria Query to get specific columns

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using Criteria Query in my code. It always fires `select * from ...`

Instead I want to neglect one column(field) from my query as that field have large number of data stored in bytes. And that causing performance issue.

Can any one give an idea for that?

---

**Some Update**

I added a projection in my query and it created a query like...

```
select
    this_.TEMPLATE_ID as y0_,
    this_.TEMPLATE_NAME as y1_,
    this_.CREATE_DATE as y2_,
    this_.UPDATE_DATE as y3_,
    this_.STATUS_CODE as y4_,
    this_.USER_ID as y5_,
    this_.UPDATED_BY as y6_,
    this_.CATEGORY_ID as y7_,
    this_.PRACTICE_ID as y8_ 
from
    templates this_ 
inner join
    user user1_ 
        on this_.USER_ID=user1_.USER_ID 
inner join
    template_categories category2_ 
        on this_.CATEGORY_ID=category2_.CATEGORY_ID 
where
    y4_=? 
    and y8_=? 
    and y5_ in (
        ?, ?
    ) 
order by
    y1_ asc limit ?
```

And now issue is like.. `Unknown column 'y4_' in 'where clause'`
and same error for y8_ , y5_ means for all where close it gave an error.

I modified it to Query like ...

```
select
    this_.TEMPLATE_ID as y0_,
    this_.TEMPLATE_NAME as y1_,
    this_.CREATE_DATE as y2_,
    this_.UPDATE_DATE as y3_,
    this_.STATUS_CODE as y4_,
    this_.USER_ID as y5_,
    this_.UPDATED_BY as y6_,
    this_.CATEGORY_ID as y7_,
    this_.PRACTICE_ID as y8_ 
from
    templates this_ 
inner join
    user user1_ 
        on this_.USER_ID=user1_.USER_ID 
inner join
    template_categories category2_ 
        on this_.CATEGORY_ID=category2_.CATEGORY_ID 
where
    this_.STATUS_CODE=1
    and this_.PRACTICE_ID=1 
    and this_.USER_ID in (
        1, 2
    ) 
order by
    y1_ asc limit ?
```

and it worked. But I don't know how to modify it in HQL?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use [Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html) to specify which columns you would like to return.

**Example**

*SQL Query*

```
SELECT user.id, user.name FROM user;
```

*Hibernate Alternative*

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
      .add(Projections.property("Name"), "Name"))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));

  List<User> list = cr.list();
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with JPA?

Comment: @cingulata yes it is possible. check this article http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select

Comment: I get 'null' for the projected properties. Why? Is this related to 'alias' stuff?

Comment: projections approach - ++1

Comment: if you got time - would you mind helping with this [Criteria API and JPQL API with GROUP BY and CONCAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129333/criteria-api-and-jpql-api-with-group-by-and-concat/73163002#73163002)

Answer (score 6):

You can use JPQL as well as JPA Criteria API for any kind of DTO projection(Mapping only selected columns to a DTO class) . Look at below code snippets showing how to selectively select various columns instead of 
selecting all columns . These example also show how to select various columns from 
joining multiple columns . I hope this helps .

JPQL code :

```
String dtoProjection = "new com.katariasoft.technologies.jpaHibernate.college.data.dto.InstructorDto"
                + "(i.id, i.name, i.fatherName, i.address, id.proofNo, "
                + " v.vehicleNumber, v.vechicleType, s.name, s.fatherName, "
                + " si.name, sv.vehicleNumber , svd.name) ";

        List<InstructorDto> instructors = queryExecutor.fetchListForJpqlQuery(
                "select " + dtoProjection + " from Instructor i " + " join i.idProof id " + " join i.vehicles v "
                        + " join i.students s " + " join s.instructors si " + " join s.vehicles sv "
                        + " join sv.documents svd " + " where i.id > :id and svd.name in (:names) "
                        + " order by i.id , id.proofNo , v.vehicleNumber , si.name , sv.vehicleNumber , svd.name ",
                CollectionUtils.mapOf("id", 2, "names", Arrays.asList("1", "2")), InstructorDto.class);

        if (Objects.nonNull(instructors))
            instructors.forEach(i -> i.setName("Latest Update"));

        DataPrinters.listDataPrinter.accept(instructors);
```

JPA Criteria API code :

```
@Test
    public void fetchFullDataWithCriteria() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = criteriaUtils.criteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<InstructorDto> cq = cb.createQuery(InstructorDto.class);

        // prepare from expressions
        Root<Instructor> root = cq.from(Instructor.class);
        Join<Instructor, IdProof> insIdProofJoin = root.join(Instructor_.idProof);
        Join<Instructor, Vehicle> insVehicleJoin = root.join(Instructor_.vehicles);
        Join<Instructor, Student> insStudentJoin = root.join(Instructor_.students);
        Join<Student, Instructor> studentInsJoin = insStudentJoin.join(Student_.instructors);
        Join<Student, Vehicle> studentVehicleJoin = insStudentJoin.join(Student_.vehicles);
        Join<Vehicle, Document> vehicleDocumentJoin = studentVehicleJoin.join(Vehicle_.documents);

        // prepare select expressions.
        CompoundSelection<InstructorDto> selection = cb.construct(InstructorDto.class, root.get(Instructor_.id),
                root.get(Instructor_.name), root.get(Instructor_.fatherName), root.get(Instructor_.address),
                insIdProofJoin.get(IdProof_.proofNo), insVehicleJoin.get(Vehicle_.vehicleNumber),
                insVehicleJoin.get(Vehicle_.vechicleType), insStudentJoin.get(Student_.name),
                insStudentJoin.get(Student_.fatherName), studentInsJoin.get(Instructor_.name),
                studentVehicleJoin.get(Vehicle_.vehicleNumber), vehicleDocumentJoin.get(Document_.name));

        // prepare where expressions.
        Predicate instructorIdGreaterThan = cb.greaterThan(root.get(Instructor_.id), 2);
        Predicate documentNameIn = cb.in(vehicleDocumentJoin.get(Document_.name)).value("1").value("2");
        Predicate where = cb.and(instructorIdGreaterThan, documentNameIn);

        // prepare orderBy expressions.
        List<Order> orderBy = Arrays.asList(cb.asc(root.get(Instructor_.id)),
                cb.asc(insIdProofJoin.get(IdProof_.proofNo)), cb.asc(insVehicleJoin.get(Vehicle_.vehicleNumber)),
                cb.asc(studentInsJoin.get(Instructor_.name)), cb.asc(studentVehicleJoin.get(Vehicle_.vehicleNumber)),
                cb.asc(vehicleDocumentJoin.get(Document_.name)));

        // prepare query
        cq.select(selection).where(where).orderBy(orderBy);
        DataPrinters.listDataPrinter.accept(queryExecutor.fetchListForCriteriaQuery(cq));

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach because it is simple and clean:

```
    String getCompaniesIdAndName = " select "
            + " c.id as id, "
            + " c.name as name "
            + " from Company c ";

    @Query(value = getCompaniesWithoutAccount)
    Set<CompanyIdAndName> findAllIdAndName();

    public static interface CompanyIdAndName extends DTO {
        Integer getId();

        String getName();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multiselect` function for this.

```
   CriteriaBuilder cb=session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cquery=cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
            Root<Car> root=cquery.from(User.class);
            cquery.multiselect(root.get("id"),root.get("Name"));
            Query<Object[]> q=session.createQuery(cquery);
            List<Object[]> list=q.getResultList();
            System.out.println("id        Name");
            for (Object[] objects : list) {
                System.out.println(objects[0]+"        "+objects[1]);
             }
```

This is supported by hibernate 5. `createCriteria` is deprecated in further version of hibernate. So you can use `criteria builder` instead.

Comment: You don't really need to map it to an Object[] array. I've just added extra constructors to my entity and it remapped to it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can map another entity based on this class (you should use entity-name in order to distinct the two) and the second one will be kind of dto (dont forget that [dto has design issues](http://avihai-java.blogspot.co.il/2010/11/single-model-no-to-presentation-model.html) ). 
you should define the second one as readonly and give it a good name in order to be clear that this is not a regular entity. 
by the way select only few columns is called projection , so google with it will be easier.

alternative - you can create named query with the list of fields that you need (you put them in the select ) or use criteria with projection