# Get only selected columns from table in object using hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am using hibernate for database communication. I have one class as:

```
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person {

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="Address_id)
private Set<Address> address;

... <other filed similarly>

}
```

Now I want to get this object using its primary key , but object should have only specific columns populate?

I tried using criteria and projection, it is returning a result but it is not mapped to Object i expect (Person Object)

Any idea how to solve this problem using hibernate query/criteria?

Thanks

Comment: Is it what you looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11626761/1292605 ?

Answer (score 0):

The hibernate annotations used have to be correctly written.

Let assume that you have two Entities: Person and Address.

```
 @Table(name="Person")
public class Person {

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name="Address_id")
private Set<Address> address;

... <other filed similarly>

}
```

And on the other side you have Address class

```
@Table(name="addresses")
public class Address{

@Column(name="name")
private String addressName;
@ManyToOne
private Person person;

}
```

Using this mapping when you have a method like:

```
 public Encounter getAddressById(int idAddress) {
    session = sf.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

  Address address = (Address ) session.load(Address .class, idAddress);

    return address ;
}
```

This should return the address mapped with person; and the display of some columns will choosen by you because hibernate here returned the entire object.