# How to get List of Table Entity with only selected columns in Hibernate using native SQL?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I am trying to execute SQL query using `session.createSQLQuery()` method of Hibernate.

`test` table has 3 columns :

- col1
- col2
- col3

**Working**

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Test.class);
List<Test> testEntityList  = query.list();
```

**Not Working**

```
String sql = "SELECT col1, col2 FROM test";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.addEntity(Test.class);
List<Test> testEntityList  = query.list();
```

Error:

> The column col3 was not found in this ResultSet.

I need to retrieve only **a few specific columns** from the table rather than the whole table.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This error means that 'XYZ' is not a column in `test`. If you do `SELECT *`, do you see `XYZ` as a column?

Comment: No Tyler column XYZ exists in the table and POJO too. For example there were 3 columns - name, age, and address. 

Now when I use sql query as "Select * from Tbl" this works fine .
But When i only select - suppose two columns - select name, age from tbl 

then the error comes as column address not found.

Comment: Ah misunderstood that this was merely a placeholder. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hibernate projections, see this answer [Hibernate Criteria Query to get specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626761/hibernate-criteria-query-to-get-specific-columns) or you can do this by changing the return type to

`List<Object[]>` and parsing it to `List<Test>`

```
    List<Object[]> testEntityList  = query.list();
    List<Test> res = new ArrayList<Test>(testEntityList.size());

    for (Object[] obj : testEntityList) {
      Test test = new Test();
      test.setCol1(obj[0]);
      test.setCol2(obj[1]);
      res.add(test);
    }
```