# Modifying the generated SQL in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, database, eclipse, hibernate

I am new to hibernate, so I have no idea about this.
Hibernate generates SQL query and fires on the database.

I was able to retrieve the query from the console, but I also wish to modify the query before it is fired.

So if the query is: `select this_.name as name189_1_ from employee this_ where this_.name=?`

1. How can I modify this query to also get the employee id?
2. Also since different databases support a slightly different syntax, how can I modify the syntax of the generated SQL query before it is fired on the database?

Comment: How are you generating the query in Java? You would need to add another filter there for employee id. How did you add the filter for `name`?

Comment: If you are using hibernate, except for really strange edge cases, you are shooting yourself in the foot by wanting to manually edit the generated sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For questions 1:**
Add projections to the criteria. Refer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626761/hibernate-criteria-query-to-get-specific-columns)

**For question 2:**
You can configure the type of SQL by setting the Dialect. Refer [Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)