# how to select specific columns for different methods?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I want to select specific columns from an entity class and neglect other columns in a method. For this I can not use @JsonIgnore because in another method I want to call all the columns available in that entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class StudentDO {
    @Id
    @Column(name="studentId")
    private int studentId;

    @Column(name="studentName")
    private String studentName;

        @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name="studentPlace")
    private String studentPlace;

    @Column(name="studentstd")
    private String studentstd;
```

Now I want a method which gives data neglecting @JsonIgnore column and another method to give all the four columns including the column with @JsonIgnore annotation when called.

Could you please help me to solve the issue

Comment: JSON has absolutely nothing to do with this. Either create a "view" class that only has a subset of columns or make a direct JPQL query.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626761/hibernate-criteria-query-to-get-specific-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved with custom entity manager query which returns `ResultSet`.

Get the `EntityManager` from SpringBoot context.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s.studentId, s.studentName FROM student s");
List<StudentDO[]> studentRows = query.getResultList();
```

For each StudentDO, the order of properties corresponds to SELECT parameter order.

For different methods, different custom queries can be written.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this except you use specific hql or spring data repositories like :

```
findStudentNameAndStudentstdBysStudentId(int studentId)
```